# Using properties to access iVars in init?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is an offshoot from a previous question, is this bad practice (using the property to set iVars)?

```
// Designated initializer 001
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)newName andType:(NSString *)newType {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self setName:newName];
        [self setType:newType];
    }
    return self;
}
```

or should I be using ...

```
// Designated initializer 002
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)newName andType:(NSString *)newType {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        name = [newName retain];
        type = [newType retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have been using version 001, but have been led to believe that using properties to access iVars in either init or dealloc is bad practice.

**EDIT:** Added `retain` to version 002

Gary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Apple [discourages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4) using accessors in init or dealloc, because they can have side effects beyond merely setting an instance variable. These are obviously undesirable in an uninitialized or destroyed object.

<sub>Exact quote from the docs: "The only places you shouldn’t use accessor methods to set an instance variable are in init methods and dealloc."</sub>

Comment: Thanks Chuck, so you would go with version 002?

Comment: @fuzzygoat: Ideally, those should be `copy` properties and the init method should copy rather than retain (because they're strings), but otherwise, yes, I'd use version 2.

Comment: @JustinXXVII: I edited the post with a link to the exact page with the advice, so you don't have to trust me. It's in the Memory Management Programming Guide, which I highly recommend to everyone who wants to code for an Apple platform.

Comment: I voted to delete my answer, it's still appearing, is it because it's voted negative?

Comment: Just curious, what could these side effects be?

Comment: @Rengers Whatever you or whoever wrote your class's superclass put into the setter method... it could be anything

Comment: @Chuck: Yeah that sounds logical. Didn't even think of that, was wondering what side effects the default synthesized methods could have.

Comment: This kind of contradicts the "The only places you shouldn’t use accessor methods to set an instance variable are in initializer methods and dealloc" statement in the Memory Management Programming Guide... "If you are using the modern runtime and synthesizing the instance variable, however, you cannot access the instance variable directly, so you must invoke the accessor method" ... More info:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW16