# Accessing property of returned object causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have a class defined where the top two properties are accessible without issue. Only the `UIColor*` is a problem. I imagine something isn't being alloc'd, init'd, retained, or released properly and have been changing various things without success. Any help would be grand.

```
// PieceScore.h

@interface PieceScore : NSObject {
    int     pieceCount;
    BOOL    greatMatch;
    UIColor *colorMatched;
}

@property (nonatomic) int pieceCount;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL greatMatch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *colorMatched;

-(id) initWithPieceCount:(int)pC withGreatMatch:(BOOL)gM withColorMatched:(UIColor*)cM;

@end


// PieceScore.m

@implementation PieceScore

@synthesize pieceCount, greatMatch, colorMatched;

-(id) init {
    return [self initWithPieceCount:0 withGreatMatch:NO withColorMatched:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

-(id) initWithPieceCount:(int)pC withGreatMatch:(BOOL)gM withColorMatched:(UIColor*)cM {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        pieceCount = pC;
        greatMatch = gM;
        colorMatched = cM;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It is initialized and returned by another class as follows:

```
PieceScore* pieceScore = [[[PieceScore alloc] initWithPieceCount:piecesRemoved withGreatMatch:greatMatch withColorMatched:pieceColor] autorelease];
return pieceScore;
```

NOTE: (`pieceColor` is a `UIColor*`)

Then, the `UIColor*` is used in a method of yet another class:

```
- (void) labelRender:(UILabel*)label withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    // ...

    label.textColor = color; // Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

    // ...
}
```

In the debug view, I can see that `color` is actually being passed as a `UIColor*`, but is error-ing out when being assigned to the label's `textColor` property.

Comment: when you write PieceScore* pieceScore = [[[PieceScore alloc] initWithPieceCount:piecesRemoved withGreatMatch:greatMatch withColorMatched:pieceColor] autorelease];
return pieceScore; you never retained/autorelease the color Object itself, you only autorelease the PieceScore. Possibly this is why it gets lost...

Comment: @Joe : Actually, something like a "label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];" still works, but assigning it otherwise does not. I've tried all the suggestions here, but still always end up with a SIGABERT or EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the ivar to an autoreleased variable. Make sure you use the property so that it is properly retained.

Change `colorMatched = cM;` to `self.colorMatched = cM;`

Comment: That logic makes sense. However, doing so causes a SIGABRT in main... "-[NSCFString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143a80" and "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143a80'"

Answer (score 0):

The ivars in your initWithPieceCount:piecesRemoved:withGreatMatch:withColorMatched need to make sure they retain any values which may be provided as autoreleased.  You shouldn't use properties within your init methods,

[See here for some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091062/using-properties-to-access-ivars-in-init)

so do a retain on the passed object.

i.e. colormatched = [cM retain];